# How to split NSString to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, theos, logos

I'm getting the APT repository name from the `Release` file.

```
Origin: blah blah
Label: This is the name
Suite: stable
Version: 1.0
Codename: ios
Architectures: iphoneos-arm
Components: main
Description: blah blah
```

`Release` file looks like this, and I want to get 'This is the name' after the 'Label:'.

So, I want to split this string to NSDictionary.
To use it like `objectForKey:@"Label"` to get `This is the name`

I get `Release` file with `AFNetworking`.

Or is there any good way to split that string and get only the name?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Basically split the string with `componentsSeparatedBy:` passing the newline character set and then populate the dictionary by splitting each line by `@": "`. `array[0].lowercaseString` is the key, `array[1]` is the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First separate your text by new line.
- Then for each line, separate by `:`.
- Then set first part as **key** and last part as **value** of dictionary.

Like this:

```
NSArray* rows = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for (NSString* row in rows) {
    NSString* key = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@": "].firstObject;
    NSString* value = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@": "].lastObject;
    [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```